# How to get the value when using Lambda in Hogan.js

Tags: javascript, hogan.js

I have the following function which handles AJAX success callback in jQuery:

```
function success(data) {
    var templateData = {
        items: data,
        formatMoney: function () {
            return function (value) {
                return Globalization.format(value, 'N');
            };
        }
    };

    // fill reports table
    var filledTable = tableTemplate.render(templateData);
    $tableContainer.html(filledTable);
}
```

Here's how my template looks like:

```
{#Items}}
<tr>
    <td>{{ProductId}}</td>
    <td>{{#formatMoney}}{{Cost}}{{/formatMoney}}</td>
</tr>
{{/Items}}
```

The problem is that instead of the value of Cost I get {{Cost}}. I know this is how it should work as it's described in mustache manual (http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html) but I'd like to get the value instead.

`this` would point to my product object so I could get cost using `this.Cost` but this is for a simple case and I have many object types with many properties that need formatting therefore I need a generic solution to keep things [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

I could also calculate this on the server side but I prefer to do this on the client side since I am not only using this data with hogan but also for other calculations on the client side.

**Is there more straightfoward, generic and client side way to get the value of Cost instead of the unrendered literal block?**

Answer (score 1):

Yep.

Mustache implementations that scrictly adhere to the spec are very limiting. Your option would be, in your lambda code, to render the "{{Cost}}" string (you should get this string and a rendering function as your lambda parameters), and parse the rendered string into a float, your cost.

Not clean, for sure. But it would work. Don't forget to open an issue in the repository of the Mustache implementation you are using.

Comment: Some other implementations have chosen to introduce support for "filters", as in {{ formatMoney(Cost) }}. See for instance https://github.com/groue/GRMustache/blob/master/Guides/filters.md

Answer (score 0):

I think we have two options.

1) Use lambdas in hogan.js

```
res.render("template", {
          lambdas:{
            formatMoney: function( cost ){
              return cost.format('usd');
            }
          });
```

and the template should be

```
{#Items}}
<tr>
    <td>{{ProductId}}</td>
    <td>{{#lambdas.formatMoney}}{{Cost}}{{/lambdas.formatMoney}}</td>
</tr>
{{/Items}}
```

2) As stated in the question, we can use this object.

Javascript code is

```
res.render("template", {
  formatMoney:{
    return function(key){
      var cost = this[key];
      return cost.format('usd');
    };
  }
});
```

and the template is

```
{#Items}}
<tr>
    <td>{{ProductId}}</td>
    <td>{{#formatMoney}}Cost{{/formatMoney}}</td>
</tr>
{{/Items}}
```