# Modify value using a lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, hogan.js

Let's say for an intance I have this template I wanted to render with [hogan.js](/questions/tagged/hogan.js):

```
var template = '{{#numbers}}'
             +     '{{#capitalize}}{{percentage}}{{/capitalize}} complete.\n'
             + '{{/numbers}}';
```

And I compile it with the ff:

```
var hello = hogan.compile(template);

var rendered = hello.render({
  numbers: [
    { percentage: .3 },
    { percentage: .6 },
    { percentage: .8 }
  ],
  capitalize: function() {
    return function(num) {
      // console.log(num);
      return num * 100;
    }
  }
})

console.log(rendered)
```

How do I get the number multiplied by 100 isntead of geting `NaN`?

```
NaN complete.
NaN complete.
NaN complete.
```

Also, when you uncomment the line above, `num = {{percentage}}` instead of the number itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the response by @akonsu, here's an example on how you might get the value for a lambda in Hogan.js.

I have two helper functions in the example, `manual` and `automatic`, which can wrap around the lambda function definition depending on the desired behavior.

```js
var source = '{{#numbers}}'
           +     'test1 = {{#test1}}{{percentage}}{{/test1}}\n'
           + '{{/numbers}}'
           + '{{#numbers}}'
           +     'test2 = {{#test2}}{{percentage}}{{/test2}}\n'
           + '{{/numbers}}';

var template = Hogan.compile(source);

var renderer = function(context) {
    return function(text) {
        return template.c.compile(text, template.options).render(context);
    };
};

var manual = function(lambda) {
    return function(text) {
        var render = renderer(this);
        return lambda.call(this, text, render);
    };
};

var automatic = function(lambda) {
    return manual(function(text, render) {
        return lambda.call(this, render(text));
    });
};

var rendered = template.render({
    numbers: [
        { percentage: .3 },
        { percentage: .6 },
        { percentage: .8 }
    ],
    test1: manual(function(text, render) {
        return render(text) * 100;
    }),
    test2: automatic(function(num) {
        return num * 100;
    })
});

console.log(rendered);
```

The output looks like this:

```
test1 = 30
test1 = 60
test1 = 80
test2 = 30
test2 = 60
test2 = 80
```

Here's a jsfiddle demonstrating the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/potatosalad/h5cU4/2/

Please note that this solution will not work with partials (if they are referenced from inside the lambda section).

The relevant code for Hogan.js 2.0.0 are [lambda replace section](https://github.com/twitter/hogan.js/blob/gh-pages/builds/2.0.0/hogan-2.0.0.js#L175-L195) and [higher order functions](https://github.com/twitter/hogan.js/blob/gh-pages/builds/2.0.0/hogan-2.0.0.js#L158-L167).

Comment: Thanks (even though I couldn't use it as I am using the hogan middleware~)! And you just utterly destroyed any positive opinions I held about hogan.js :O

Comment: but i found this does not work on later hogan.js version like 3.0.2, i guess might be hogan's some function has been changed, i am still looking for best chooice

Comment: with the latter version, i found this is working well `{
  "wrapped": function() {
    return function(text) {
      return Hogan.compile(text).render(this);
    }
  }
}`  [link](https://github.com/twitter/hogan.js/issues/222)

Answer (score 0):

I think this example is relevant: https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#functions. My guess is that this should help:

```
capitalize: function() {
  return function(text, render) {
    return render(text) * 100;
  }
}
```

a similar post: [How to get the value when using Lambda in Hogan.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460350/how-to-get-the-value-when-using-lambda-in-hogan-js)

Comment: I get an `undefined is not a function`.

Answer (score 0):

```
capitalize: function(num) {
   return num * 100;
}
```

should work for you